Physical or mathematical boundary conditions for quarter wavelength standing wave or anti-node
In physics books and online articles, the quarter-wavelength standing wave is typically explained using the concepts of nodes and antinodes as boundary conditions, which are extremely idealized representations. I am curious about the actual physical or mathematical boundary conditions in the context of acoustics or elasticity.
Mathematical boundary conditions, such as Dirichlet and Neumann conditions, are often simplifications of the underlying physical boundary conditions. If the actual physical boundary conditions are too complex to explain, a simpler mathematical boundary condition for a 1D wave PDE would suffice.
Physically, when a wave encounters a much stiffer medium, it effectively experiences a node or zero Dirichlet boundary condition. But what about anti-nodes? is it represented by zero Neumann boundary condition? and what properties of the medium cause this behaivior?
